# How do I authenticate when calling an abp.io application REST Endpoint?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, abp

I have a .Net Core application built with ABP.IO using the basic CLI. It exposes a swagger interface for basic user management and login etc. I can call any of the [Authorize]'d these end points from javascript once logged in or via Swagger OK. However this must be using some sort of authentication technique.

If I want to call the endpoints from  curl or from another application how do I authenticate and get an access_token etc.?

I can call the login methods but they just return success on successful login. Is there a way to get an auth token or something to be able to then make calls to end points that require authentication.

This seems like a very natural thing to do

Answer (score 0):

If your application is built with angular version. Angular Home compenent have already imported OAuthService. You can call OAuthService.getAccessToken(), and may copy to clipboard etc.

```
// this is already in template
get hasLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.oAuthService.hasValidAccessToken();
}

// you can add this to read bearer access token
get token(): string {
    return this.oAuthService.getAccessToken();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else, I couldn't get the token via OAuthService, but I did get it via TokenService.

I injected it into the constructor and then called getToken()

```
this.tokenService.getToken()
```